# Leaflet - Folium : Creating a fantasy map, removing the world map

Tags: leaflet, folium

I'm trying to create an interactive map out of an image using Folium as part of a Django project in which I want to display the generated HTML on a website.
I want to be able to see **only the image** upon which I place markers etc., not the actual world map that is by default created.
The image is a map of a fantasy world.

I found [this](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) tutorial and tried to apply it to Folium and that generally worked. I'm essentially adding an Image Overlay with "my" map to a map-object. However, that does not remove the original real-world map, meaning when I then save this map, it still also displays a world map that I do not care about in the lower left corner attached to my image overlay.

```
import folium

def create_aldrune_map():
    base_map = folium.Map(crs='Simple', zoom_start=4)

    aldrune_overlay = folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
        image='Path/To/Image',
        bounds=[[0, 0], [1000, 1300]],
        zindex=1)
    aldrune_overlay.add_to(base_map)
    base_map.fit_bounds(bounds=[[0, 0], [1000, 1300]])

    base_map.save('Path/To/Output')
```

[image: Aldrune's Map]
How do I get rid of the real-world map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote from the [Folium documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html), emphasis mine:

> `class folium.folium.Map(location=None, width='100%', height='100%', left='0%', top='0%', position='relative', tiles='OpenStreetMap',` 
> (snip)
> `, **kwargs)`
>
> Parameters
>
> `tiles` *(str, default 'OpenStreetMap')* – Map tileset to use. Can choose from a list of built-in tiles, pass a custom URL or **pass `None` to create a map without tiles**. For more advanced tile layer options, use the `TileLayer` class.

Therefore you probably want something like:

> ```
> base_map = folium.Map(crs='Simple', zoom_start=4, tiles=None)
> ```

Comment: *wow* The fact that I spent literal hours searching due to the fact that I apparently can't read... man there are moments one can only be disappointed in ones self.
Thank you so much for highlighting this mistake of mine, this answer works flawlessly.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes :-)

Comment: Great solution, now is it possible to show only specific country with it ? @IvanSanchez